# How to delete data from database by using radio button in php?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Actually here is the main problem. It does not get the value of "$radio[$i]" statement that can be used as a condition here. So will anyone please tell me what I have to write there instead of "$radio[$i]" as the output will come.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $del_id = $radio[$i];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM reigster WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($del_id)."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    if($result)
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_multiple.php\">";
    }
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: And looking at your code, the PHP seems to be intended to handle multiple deletes at once, but shouldn't your input be of the type checkbox instead?

Comment: On the right path you are, little grasshoppa! On html skills you must practise first!

Comment: What's the radio button name?

Comment: I HAVE USED IT BUT IT DOES NOT WORK. IT IS STILL THERE.

Answer (score 0):

After looking to your previous question The problem is in this code of block

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 {
 $del_id = $radio[$i];
 $sql = "DELETE FROM reigster WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($del_id)."'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 }
```

Replace above with this code

```
     $count=count($_POST['radio']); 
     for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
     {
       $del_id = $_POST['radio'][$i];
       $sql = "DELETE FROM reigster WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($del_id)."'";
       $result = mysql_query($sql);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($_POST['radio'] as $del_id)
 {
   $sql = "DELETE FROM reigster WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($del_id)."'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $del_id = $radio['checked'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM reigster WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($del_id)."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    if($result)
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_multiple.
```